# JQuery menu with background image animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/bnNSW/
I want a functional navigation menu. How?

1. On click background must animate to bottom in order to select and link to a page. At the same time another selected tabs must animate to top.
2. On hover background must show just the tip to demostrate user all tabs are selectable.

Code?

UPDATE: This is the site i'm working on http://www.accastelli.com.ar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [demo](http://jsbin.com/usijof/3/edit)

```
$("#nav li a").hover(
function () {
    //$("#nav li a li").css({'background-position-y':'-102px'});
    if( $(this).parent('li').not('select') ){
        $(this).parent('li').animate({'background-position-y':'-82px'},300);
    }
},
function () {
    if( $(this).parent('li').not('select') ){
        $(this).parent('li').animate({'background-position-y':'-102px'},300);
    }
}
);

$('#nav li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#nav li').animate({'background-position-y':'-102px'},300,function(){ $('#nav li').removeClass('select');});

      $(this).parent('li').animate({'background-position-y':'0'},300,function(){$(this).addClass('select')});
});
```

Comment: I uploaded this last code. There's a glitch where two buttons are selected at once. Almost there. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Also i uploaded link to the page i'm working. I included .parentsUntil("#nav") to avoid code interfering with other links in this site.

Comment: updated my code `$('#nav li').removeClass('select');` in the click function please try now

Comment: I think that the parent function is not addressing properly the li's in the html. Is there a way to apply the removeClass func recursively-ish on each li no matter how many? That was the problem in the first place. Thanks for your help. I suck at jQuery, it's a nightmare to do the code for the web pages I style.

Comment: ` $('#nav li').removeClass('select');` should remove all the select from li recursively and you have not yet updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UE9B2/)

```
 $("#nav li a").hover(
    function () {
        if ($(this).parent('li').not('select')) {
            $(this).parent('li').animate({ 'background-position-y': '-82px' }, 300);
        }
    },
    function () {
        if ($(this).parent('li').not('select')) {
            $(this).parent('li').animate({ 'background-position-y': '-102px' }, 300);
        }
    }
);

        $('#nav li a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).parents().find('li').removeClass('select');
            $(this).parent('li').animate({ 'background-position-y': '0' },
                                        {
                                            duration: 300,
                                            complete: function () { $(this).addClass('select'); }
                                        }
                                    );

        });
```

Comment: animations aren't working at http://jsfiddle.net/UE9B2/ don't know exact reason, BUT if you copy those scripts from the link and run them on your system properly it'll work for sure on Chrome too.